# Toggle for multiple checkboxes – prototype js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, toggle

I'm trying to implement a toggle for multiple checkboxes but if I switch one manually, the checkbox is no longer considered by toggle.

```js
var publishAll = $("toggle");
publishAll.observe('click', function(e){
 var state = null;
 if(this.checked) {
  state = "checked";
 } 
 $$('.checkbox').invoke('writeAttribute', 'checked', state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="true"> Toggle checkbox<br /><br />
    
check these manually and it won't work with toggle anymore.<br />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1"><br />
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: i'm baffled :\ code looks fine to me, i see nothing change in the inspector when i toggle them by hand...

Comment: I'm baffled, too. And I really don't know how to solve this problem semantically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the attribute of checked to "checked" you need to use the javascript `true` or `false` as well as use the `setValue()` method

So you can simplify your javascript like this

```
$("toggle").observe('click', function(e){
  $$('.checkbox').invoke('setValue',this.checked);
});
```